# Can't enter Heroku bash. Error says EHOSTUNREACH

Tags: heroku, ehostunreach

Trying to deploy my app on Heroku but can't get into bash

```
Running bash on ⬢ myapp... !
```

▸    EHOSTUNREACH: connect EHOSTUNREACH 50.19.103.36:5000

Does anyone know what this means?
When I try to run the app, logs says

```
Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
```

I'm unable to trace the problem

Comment: That looks like something that should resolve itself. Have you tried again?

Comment: Yes I've tried repeatedly.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I try to run the app"? The app should run automatically once it's been deployed.

Comment: When I try to access the deployed site, I look at heroku logs to see why it's not working and I see Error R13. Then when I try to enter bash or use any command under "Heroku run" it says EHOSTUNREACH. It does that every time.

Comment: Did this application ever work on Heroku?

Comment: Yes I did have an earlier version running, I was using a Macbook at the time. Now I'm using a Chromebook with Linux.

Comment: I've had success using a different network. Thanks for the interest

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a network issue that was resolved by using a different one.